# SpringBoot - activiti - Get ProcessVariables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, alfresco, activiti

I have this piece of code :

```
    List<ProcessInstance> instances =
                    processEngine.getRuntimeService().createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId).list();

instances.forEach(this::listProcessInstance);

    private void listProcessInstance (ProcessInstance processInstance) {
    
                log.info("<-------------- ProcessInstance ---------------> {} ", processInstance);
                log.info(String.valueOf(processInstance.getProcessVariables()));
                log.info("<-------------- ProcessInstance --------------->");
    
    
        }
```

where ProcessVariables is null, but going on the tabla there are info:

```
select * from ACT_RU_VARIABLE where PROC_INST_ID_ = 76759;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance reasons the default query does not return the process variables. You have to explicitly tell the query to include the variables:

```
 List<ProcessInstance> instances = processEngine.getRuntimeService().createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId).includeProcessVariables().list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code snippet,

```
ProcessInstanceQuery processInstanceQuery = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceIds(processInstanceIds);
  
    List<ProcessInstance> processInstances = processInstanceQuery.list();
  
    for (ProcessInstance processInstance : processInstances) {
      log.info(processInstance.getId());
      log.info(processInstance.getProcessVariables());
    }
```